# Is it possible to install package from git repository from downloaded .zip file in npm?

Tags: npm

I've downloaded manually master branch of repository via `Download ZIP` button on GitHub. Now, my question is:

> Is it possible to install package from git repository from downloaded
>   .zip file in npm?

Running:

```
$ npm install ~/Pobrane/lwip-master.zip
```

Failed:

```
npm ERR! not a package /home/name/Pobrane/lwip-master.zip
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /home/name/Pobrane/lwip-master.zip
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-11-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "/home/name/Pobrane/lwip-master.zip"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.4
npm ERR! path /tmp/npm-4968-42fe38a2/unpack-56722f88bedcd792268b060f241bf5f9/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/npm-4968-42fe38a2/unpack-56722f88bedcd792268b060f241bf5f9/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/name/Projects/api/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Link to repository? My first instinct is that there is no `package.json`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this :

```
npm install ./package.zip
```

Reference: 
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: file should be .tar, tar.gz or .tgz

Answer (score 2):

It doesnot work with the github zip download unless you unzip the package with his name as the main directory and request the installation with npm on this root directory

Example

```
download material-design-icons from github
unzip to the directory of your project (or c:\tmp) 
npm install  ./material-design-icons
```

or
    npm install  c:/tmp/material-design-icons

It work nicely and fast!