# Is it possible to install package from git repository via downloading zip files in npm?

Tags: angularjs, git, npm-install

I am trying to install angular packages after downloading there zip files from git hub as my company policies doesn't allow to install directly via NPM.
I have tried this link "[Is it possible to install package from git repository from downloaded .zip file in npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850521/is-it-possible-to-install-package-from-git-repository-from-downloaded-zip-file)" but it does not work for me.Any ideas.

Comment: try unzip and position on the unzip folder an do a npm install ex: `cd c:\unzip`  then `npm install`

Comment: The folder does not have a package.json file. Also while trying to run npm install it is once again redirecting to npm registry which I have not been able to connect.

Comment: some npm no needs to install, some function like bower, just create the src path to them or require and they will work, for angular no needs to install, however gulp, grunt, yeoman, and other dependencies they it needs to install with npm.

Comment: Angular 4 needs the proper node_modules structure.I am not sure whether we can achieve it via just unzipping the files and also if I create the src path , which would be the entry file is also a relevant question