# How can I install create-react-app when url where it is downloaded is blocked?

Tags: installation, create-react-app

At my work I've got everything blocked, I could install node.js with npm, but when I wanted to install react-app I found that I can't do that cause It downloads it and then install it. The only thing that I can do is downloading as zip from the repository.

Is there a way to install it with that zip?

Comment: Clone with git?

Comment: Also clone is not an option, but I could download the project in a zip, now I don't know If there's a way to install everything by hand without running the npm install command.

Comment: Have you tried placing the extracted zip in nodemodules

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850521/is-it-possible-to-install-package-from-git-repository-from-downloaded-zip-file